# Regex with multiple filters

Tags: regex

I Want to create a filter that will match the following string with the following interface

```
 Date: dd/mm/yyyy-dd/mm/yyyy
 Name: string
 ID: string
```

The string itself:
`Date: 11/02/2020,Name:SO,ID:10`

The Regex I tried look like this ->

```
(Date:((((([13578]|0[13578]|1[02])[\/](0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(([469]|0[469]|11)[\/]([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0]))|((2|02)([\/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))))[\/](19([6-9][0-9])|20([0-9][0-9])))|((02)[\/](29)[\/](19(6[048]|7[26]|8[048]|9[26])|20(0[048]|1[26]|2[048]))))(-)?((((([13578]|0[13578]|1[02])[\/](0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(([469]|0[469]|11)[\/]([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0]))|((2|02)([\/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))))[\/](19([6-9][0-9])|20([0-9][0-9])))|((02)[\/](29)[\/](19(6[048]|7[26]|8[048]|9[26])|20(0[048]|1[26]|2[048]))))?|Name|ID)`
```

The problem I have with this regex is that it just captures the first filter.

Comment: Can you give examples of strings that should match / not match ?

Comment: It's because of `...|Name|ID`. This is matching date **or** `Name` (literally) **or** `ID` (literally). You likely want to change the `|Name|ID` portion to something like `Name:[a-zA-Z]+`. Also, it's unclear, but if you're only getting one match and expecting multiple, you likely have to make your regex perform global matching. Not sure which language you're using, but this is done differently in each regex engine. Many use the `g` modifier to indicate global matching, but often languages also utilize a method that allows for multiple matches - e.g. `findall` vs `search` for [tag:python]

Comment: I would also suggest you step back and read your question again, but try to do so without any preconceived knowledge of your issue. It seems you know exactly what you need, but haven't articulated that very well to us. Give us multiple strings that should be matched (in all the forms you expect the regex to work) and the same for strings that should not match. Also, give us the makeup of each part: What characters are valid for name/id? What date formats are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your problem, so I created a regex that matches the string you want, whatever are the dates or the names :

```
Date: (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})-(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\sName:([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Gmy6nv/2).

Can you edit your post and give more examples of strings that must match and strings that must not ?

Comment: I need the Name to be optional as the id so for example in some cases it will just match for name sometimes for name and date sometimes for name,date,id

Comment: If I understand well, [this](https://regex101.com/r/Gmy6nv/3) is what you need. Am I right ?
If there is dates, they will be matched in groups 3 and 4. If there is a name, it will be matched in group 5, and if there is an ID it will be matched in group 7.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm searching for

Comment: For your next stackoverflow questions, please give examples of the strings you want to match (refer to @ctwheels comment to know what you need to give us). It will be easier for us to help you ;)